# KeyDown event in wpf hyperlink

Tags: wpf, xaml, hyperlink, keydown

I need to perform some operations on the keydown event on a wpf hyperlink.

I have a simple richtextbox in which i have a hyperlink. I want Keydown event to be fired only when the focus is on the hyperlink, that is the cursor is on the hyperlink text.

Doing this doesn't work and i couldn't find any explanation of why this doesn't work.

```
<Hyperlink KeyDown="Hyperlink_KeyDown">
   test
</Hyperlink>
```

I would really appreciate it if you could help me.

Thanks.
Have a good day, 
Astig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it doesn't work because hyperlink isn't recognized like focused, you may catch this event in parent control for example grid but before it will be caught you must click on it.

So you may catch window's keydown event like this:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    Name="MW" KeyDown="MW_KeyDown">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock>
        <Hyperlink Name="HL1" NavigateUri="http://www.google.com/" RequestNavigate="HL1_RequestNavigate">
               Focus it and key down
        </Hyperlink>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

and code:

```
 private void MW_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (HL1.IsMouseOver == true)
            HL1_RequestNavigate(HL1,new RequestNavigateEventArgs(HL1.NavigateUri, HL1.Name));
    }

    private void HL1_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

**Edit**

Also you can set focus to hyperlink like that:

XAML:

```
<Hyperlink Name="HL1" NavigateUri="http://www.google.com/" RequestNavigate="HL1_RequestNavigate" KeyDown="HL1_KeyDown" MouseEnter="HL1_MouseEnter">
```

code:

```
private void HL1_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void HL1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        HL1_RequestNavigate(HL1, new RequestNavigateEventArgs(HL1.NavigateUri, HL1.Name));
    }

    private void HL1_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        HL1.Focus();
    }
```